# Advanced sort options for questions?

Tags: discussion, searching

Is there a way to do sorting of questions based on:

- number of views?
- number of views per (some time frame)
- frequently asked, without answers
- number of votes for questions, without answers
- number or user reputation

Or other options for sorting and searching for questions I might care about answering.
perhaps I am simply missing options for searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## If you need advanced sorting: Stack Exchange Data Explorer

([Link](https://data.stackexchange.com/))

([DBSchema Documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678))

(**As per [Dan's comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13805/advanced-sort-options-for-questions/13806?noredirect=1#comment23728_13806), [the data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq)**)

- ### [Most viewed questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/298608/most-viewed-questions)

```
SELECT TOP ##Number## Id AS [Post Link], ViewCount
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC;

-- Number: Number of posts to show:
```

- ### [Most viewed questions between date X and date Y](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/298621/most-viewed-questions-between-date-x-and-date-y)

```
SELECT TOP ##Number## Id AS [Post Link], ViewCount, CreationDate
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 AND CreationDate BETWEEN ##FromCreationDate:string## AND ##ToCreationDate:string##
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC;

-- Number: Number of posts to show:
-- FromCreationDate: From YYYY-MM-DD
-- ToCreationDate: To YYYY-MM-DD
```

- ### [Most frequently asked (not answered) questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/298604/most-frequently-asked-not-answered-questions)

```
SELECT TOP ##Number## a.Id AS [Post Link], b.NumberOfDuplicates
FROM Posts AS a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Posts.Id, COUNT(PostLinks.RelatedPostId) AS NumberOfDuplicates
FROM Posts, PostLinks
WHERE Posts.Id = PostLinks.RelatedPostId AND PostLinks.LinkTypeId = 3
GROUP BY Posts.Id)
AS b ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE a.AnswerCount = 0
ORDER BY b.NumberOfDuplicates DESC;

-- Number: Number of posts to show:
```

- ### [Most voted (not closed and not answered) questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/298628/most-voted-not-closed-and-not-answered-questions)

```
SELECT TOP ##Number## Id AS [Post Link], Score
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 AND ClosedDate IS NULL AND AnswerCount = 0
ORDER BY Score DESC;

-- Number: Number of posts to show:
```

- [Latest (not closed) questions from users with reputation

```
SELECT TOP ##Number## Posts.Id AS [Post Link], Users.Reputation
FROM Posts, Users
WHERE Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id AND Posts.PostTypeId = 1 AND Posts.ClosedDate IS NULL AND Users.Reputation < ##UserReputationThreshold##
ORDER BY Posts.CreationDate DESC;

-- Number: Number of posts to show:
-- UserReputationThreshold: User's reputation threshold:
```

Comment: For user reputation, I mean users with less that 500 rep for example.  How come the compose query button isn't in the ask Ubuntu page (or is it? I never saw it, but that is definitely the thing i want.)

Comment: Now That I am looking, in the database Scheme, there is Reputation an int.

Comment: @j0h Well aside from the fact that you must know a bit of `SQL` to use it, it's not useful for most of the users. I think moderators have their own prebuilt tools to do more advanced tasks

Comment: @j0h I'm building that query as well

Comment: Will it always ask me If I am a bot? / capcha?   .... I prolly ought to learn some more SQL but feel free to keep helping lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: @j0h You're welcome, I think you need to login with OpenID via Stack Exchange to get rid of the captcha

Comment: @j0h How do you need the last query to be sorted, latest first I guess?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great

Comment: @j0h Addedd, I also added a link to the DBSchema documentation as a reference for building new queries

Comment: @j0h I'm stopping here commenting before a moderator moves everything to the chat, but notice that the last one is not very useful because all those queries are sent to a database dump which is a few days older

Comment: Just a side note that probably should be mentioned. The data in the data explorer is not very up-to-date. It is updated once per week. [Mondays around 3:00 UTC](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) to be more precise.

Comment: @Dan True, updated

Answer (score 1):

## If you don't need advanced sorting: Regular search

Scraped from [How do I search?](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching)

### How do I search?

Enter search terms in the search box that appears in the upper right corner of every page, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you need to refine and narrow your search, here are some basic tips:

- To search within specific tag(s), enter them in square brackets: `[maintenance] seat` searches for mentions of "seat" within the [maintenance] tag.
- To find a specific phrase, or to search a string of special characters, enter it in quotes: like `"flat tire"`, or `"<%#"`.
- To limit your search to just the title of a question, use `title:` followed by the search term. Likewise, search the body only (exclude the title) with `body:"phrase here"`.
- To search *just your* posts: `user:me training` searches all of your posts for the word "training".
- To *exclude* results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with `-` in your query: `waffles -unicorns` finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while `[laurel] -[hardy]` includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.
- Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk (`*`) anywhere in the word, like `encour*` or `Ex*nge`.

### Advanced Search Options:

We offer a number of advanced search operators to help you find very specific information.

#### Range Operators

To search for only questions that fall within a particular range for **score**, number of **answers**, or number of **views**, you can enter an upper or lower parameter, or a range.

- `score:-1` or `score:-1..` will both return posts with a score greater than or equal to -1
- `views:500..1000` or `views:500-1000` will return posts with 500 to 1000 views
- `answers:..3` will return questions with 3 or fewer answers

#### Dates

You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:

- `created:` to specify when the posts were created
- `lastactive:` for posts active in a specified time period

Dates can be entered in the following formats:

- Absolute dates:

  - *year only* – e.g., `created:2012..2013` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013; `created:2012` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012.
  - *year and month* – e.g., `created:2012-04..2012-05` searches posts created between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012.
  - *day, month, and year* – e.g., `lastactive:2012-04-03` searches posts who were last active between 12:00 AM on April 3, 2012 and 11:59 PM on April 3, 2012.
- Relative dates:

  - `1y`, `1m`, and `1d` are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday" - e.g., if today is April 15, `created:1m` searches posts created between March 1 and March 31. (You can substitute any number for `1` to look back that many years, months, or days.)
  - Relative datas in a range (`1y..`) look back to the same date in the previous period - e.g., if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use `lastactive:3m..` On April 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can close the range as well: `lastactive:3m..1m`.

**Please note** that all times are recorded in UTC; the results may not match your timezone.

#### User Operators

You can also limit searches to a specific user's content (your own or someone else's). You will need the user id to search another user's posts.

- `user:mine` or `user:me` (or any user id) returns only your posts (or only the posts from whichever user whose id you entered)
- `infavorites:mine` (or any user id) returns only questions that you (or the user whose id you entered) have favorited.
- `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite. (If you don't have any tags, this operator does nothing. For better results, update your preferences.)

#### Boolean Operators

The following search operators can be used with values of yes/no, true/false, or 1/0 (each pair behaves the same):

- `isaccepted:` yes/true/1 returns only **answers** that have been marked "accepted"; no/false/0 returns only answers that are not marked accepted.
- `hascode:` yes/true/1 returns only posts that contain code blocks; no/false/0 returns only posts that contain *no* code.
- `hasaccepted:` yes/true/1 returns only **questions** that have accepted answers; no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted answers.
- `isanswered:` yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least [one accepted or positively-scored answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/); no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted or positively-scored answers.
- `closed:` yes/true/1 returns only questions that are closed; no/false/0 excludes closed questions from the search.
- `duplicate:` yes/true/1 returns questions that have been marked as a duplicate of another question; no/false/0 excludes duplicate questions from the search.
- `migrated:` yes/true/1 returns only questions that have been migrated to a different site; no/false/0 excludes migrated questions from the search.
- `locked:` yes/true/1 returns only locked posts (which have edits, votes, comments, and new answers disabled); no/false/0 returns only posts that are not locked.
- `hasnotice:` yes/true/1 returns only posts with a notice shown below them; no/false/0 returns only posts that do not have a notice applied.
- `wiki:` yes/true/1 returns only [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) posts; no/false/0 returns only non-community wiki posts.

#### OR operator

To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": `[widgets] or [geegaws]` returns questions tagged with *either* tag.

#### Miscellaneous Operators

- `url:"example.com"` searches for posts containing the url "example.com"
- `is:question` narrows results down to just questions, and `is:answer` returns only answers
- `inquestion:50691` restricts the search to the question with id 50691. If you are searching using the search box on a question page, you can use `inquestion:this` to restrict results to the post you are already viewing.