# Syntax highlighting doesn’t work on meta

Tags: bug, code-formatting

When I enter

> <!-- language-all: lang-bash -->
>
> ```
>     if :; then echo "quoted"; fi
> ```

in a post on main, the output looks like this:

[image: example for proper syntax highlighting on main]

Here on meta, the very same code gets no syntax highlighting at all:

```
if :; then echo "quoted"; fi
```

I already tried every possible combination from `language: bash` to said `language-all: lang-bash` without any avail. As the last paragraphs in [this post by Eliah Kagan](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17167/507051) shows, I’m not the only one who is [bothered](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17899/507051) by this – I think we all agree syntax highlighting is very useful.

Could you shed some light on whether that’s actually a bug or rather [status-bydesign](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?
If it’s the latter:

- What are the precise reasons this decision was made?
- Can we have a discussion on that?

---

> When is syntax highlighting needed in meta? The only case I can think of is a question asking about syntax highlighting. Is that really a common enough issue to need it?

There are a number of scripts and code snippets posted here on meta, examples in addition to the above linked ones include:

- code copied from main for analysis: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15292/507051
  that’s a case where syntax highlighting would be *especially* useful
- [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) SQL scripts: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13806/507051
- SVG code: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2631/507051 and https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2640/507051
- scripts requested by OP: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13905/507051, https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/483/507051 and https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/294/507051

Is there any good reason *not* to have syntax highlighting available?

Comment: By design: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120812/270345

Comment: When is syntax highlighting needed in meta? The only case I can think of is a question asking about syntax highlighting. Is that really a common enough issue to need it?

Comment: @terdon good question, see edit :)